# Spring mongodb add or update a list of documents

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongo, spring-mongodb

I have a list of records like

```
[
    {"id":"1", "name":"a", "user":"u1"},
    {"id":"2", "name":"b", "user":"u1"},
    {"id":"3", "name":"c", "user":"u1"}
]
```

Now based on if an entry already exists or not in the database, it should either update or insert the document. Also for update there is a condition that the value of existing `user` field should match the supplied value for `user` in the document.

Of course I can run the list in a loop and use

```
mongoOperations.save(...);
```

But if I have a huge list then I will have to do one db operation per each entry which I don't think is efficient. Is there any other efficient way to perform this operation?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the CRUD repository then the CRUD repository provides the save() method which can be used for the single entity(mongoCollection) or you can use the overloaded save method

```
<S extends T> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entites)
```

which can take the Arraylist  and saves arraylist object. No need to use the loops.

You can see the below example in which InventoryService class create a 3 Inventory Objects and add all in ArrayList and finally pass this to inventory repository which is a CRUD repository.

```
@Service
public class InventoryService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InventoryService.class);

    @Autowired
    private InventoryRepository inventoryRepository;

    public void aveInventoryDetails() {

        List<Inventory> inventoryList = new ArrayList<Inventory>();

        inventoryList.add(new Inventory("500", 10));
        inventoryList.add(new Inventory("600", 20));
        inventoryList.add(new Inventory("700", 30));

        try {
            inventoryRepository.saveAll(inventoryList);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Mongo Repository

```
package com.bjs.repository;

import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

import com.bjs.model.Inventory;

public interface InventoryRepository extends MongoRepository<Inventory, String> {

// empty as not defining any new method , we can use the existing save method   

}
```

For reference - http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-commons/1.9.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-java.lang.Iterable-

Comment: Or implement the loop by your own - `CrudRepository`'s implementation uses loop.

Comment: Is it possible to store -- List<Document> mappedResults = aggregate.getMappedResults();
List<Document> by saveAll

Answer (score 2):

You can use mongoTemplate.updateMulti() for updating list of record as below

```
Query query = new Query(); 
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("filteringField").is("filteringFieldValue));
Update update = new Update();
update.set("fieldToBeUpdated", "fieldToBeUpdatedValue");
mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, YourClass.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
mongoTemplate.insertAll(entities);
```